# M2 - How to add admin user with different role from console?

Tags: magento2

As per [magento doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html#instgde-cli-admin), I am supposed to create an admin user as following:

```
<path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

That's fine. Now suppose, I have a different role called `reseller` which has limited access to the admin. How do I assign that role if I create an user through console, or is this not possible?

In case this is not possible, can this be done through SQL queries? I have an external app which creates new sub stores and creates an admin user (who can only view the content of that store) for that store. I have managed to restrict the users to their stores but not sure how I can create that user while creating the instance of the sub-store.